# How do I display a Form on top of a full screen application?

Tags: c#, winforms, topmost

I made a local chat that is displayed on the screen in the upper-right corner on top of all windows (`TopMost = true`).
The chat itself is displayed on a Form that is semi-transparent, setup to click-through.

Unfortunately, the app is not visible when using any full screen app.
How to display a Form on top of full screen applications?

Comment: this should still work: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kirtan007/make-form-stay-always-on-top-of-every-window/

Comment: Making your app a tray utility is another way around it, the tray is a useful way to get between apps and still raise some notifications without getting in the way of the user.